# Ordering a Django QuerySet by a datetime's month/day?

Tags: django, datetime, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I have a list of people, each person having a birthdate, which is predictably stored in a `DateField`. I'm trying to create a list of those people—sorted by the *month* and *day* of their birth (disregarding the year)—to have a sort of "who's birthday is coming up" display.

I can't seem to order a `QuerySet` by the person's `datetime.month` value. Is there any way that this could be done without having to resort to coercing to a `list()`?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if the question needs clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`QuerySet.extra()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) to define a month field and sort by it:

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(select={'birthmonth': 'MONTH(birthdate)'},
    order_by=['birthmonth'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Just wanted to clarify for those that use PostgreSQL to replace `MONTH(birthdate)` with `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM birthdate)`.

Comment: Correct method name is extra

Comment: As much as I love this answer, it appears that the QuerySet.extra() method is on the chopping block and will eventually be deprecated.  The django docs state, "Use this method as a last resort" and "This is an old API that we aim to deprecate at some point in the future."

Answer (score 11):

> For django >= **2.1**

You can sort the QuerySet by using month and day lookup names on DateField.

```
SomeModel.objects.order_by('birth_date__month', 'birth_date__day')
```

> For django >= **1.10**

Use database-function [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) to generate extra month and day columns by [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) method, then `order_by` these columns you can sort the `QuerySet` by their birthday only.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract

SomeModel.objects.annotate(
    birth_date__month = Extract('birth_date', 'month'),
    birth_date__day = Extract('birth_date', 'day')
).order_by('birth_date__month', 'birth_date__day')
```

> For **older django versions**

For older `django` versions you can do the same using [QuerySet.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra), but you have to write *database specific query*.

- *MySQL*

  ```
  SomeModel.objects.extra(select={
          'birth_date_month': 'MONTH(birth_date)',
          'birth_date_day': 'DAY(birth_date)'
      },
      order_by=['birth_date_month','birth_date_day']
  )
  ```
- *PostgreSQL*

  ```
  SomeModel.objects.extra(select={
          'birth_date_month': 'EXTRACT(MONTH FROM birth_date)',
          'birth_date_day': 'EXTRACT(DAY FROM birth_date)'
      },
      order_by=['birth_date_month','birth_date_day']
  )
  ```
- *SQlite*

  ```
  SomeModel.objects.extra(select={
          'birth_date_month': 'strftime("%m", birth_date)',
          'birth_date_day': 'strftime("%d", birth_date)'
      },
      order_by=['birth_date_month','birth_date_day']
  )
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of django have the lookup on DateFields and DateTimeFields.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#extract

`MyModel.objects.order_by('birthday__month', 'birthday__day')`

Answer (score 1):

## I tested using django 1.10.8

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract
from your_project.your_app.models import Person


CHOICE_MONTH = (
    (None, '--'),
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 5),
    (6, 6),
    (7, 7),
    (8, 8),
    (9, 9),
    (10, 10),
    (11, 11),
    (12, 12),
)

class PersonSearchForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField(label=u'name', required=False)
    month = forms.ChoiceField(label='month', choices=CHOICE_MONTH, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.corporation = kwargs.pop('corporation', None)
        super(PersonSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_result_queryset(self):
        q = Q(corporation=self.corporation)
        if self.is_valid():
            name = self.cleaned_data['name']
            if name:
                q = q & Q(name__icontains=name)
            month = self.cleaned_data['month']
            if month:
                q = q & Q(month=int(month))

        return Person.objects.annotate(month=Extract('birthday', 'month'),
                                       day=Extract('birthday', 'day')).filter(q).order_by('month', 'day')
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Post.objects.all().order_by('date_posted__minute').reverse()
where date_posted is your attribute you used in your Post model.

> Post is just an example model

Comment: Hi Janaki, thanks for posting! Adding more details to your answer and using the terminology they use, (birth month / day, rather than date_posted), will help the poster understand your answer without the need for them to ask follow up questions. Take a look at the other answers to this question to get a feel for what is needed.  It also helps to [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).