# Get pub_date value using filters

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I need some help for learning how to get "Datetime" value using filters.

I'm working for getting a table which shows Sales order by year.

How can I improve my code for getting it?

models.py

```
 class Ventas(models.Model):
      codigoventa = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
      codigocliente = models.ForeignKey('Clientes')
      Fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField("Fecha de edicion", auto_now_add=True) 
      totalventa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places = 2)
      codigosucursal = models.ForeignKey('Sucursales')
      totalventa = models.IntegerField()

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.codigoventa
      class Meta:
            ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

views.py

```
def ventas_anio(request):
    ventas = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro=datetime(2013, 1, 30))
    return render_to_response('ventasanual.html',{'datos':ventas}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter by certain date, either

```
import datetime
the_day = datetime.date(2013, 1, 30)
Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__gte=the_day, 
                      Fecha_registro__lt=the_day+datetime.timedelta(1))
```

Or

```
Ventas.objects.extra(where=["DATE(Fecha_registro)=%s"], params=['2013-01-30'])
```

Or inefficient but workable

```
Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__year=2013, 
                      Fecha_registro__month=1,
                      Fecha_registro__day=30)
```

The doc of `gte`, `lt`, `extra`, `year`, `month` and `day` is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: thanks it works but ...Can I do the same for sorting by month?                for example shows sales by month.

Comment: @dcft This could be tricky. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236226/ordering-a-django-queryset-by-a-datetimes-month-day , replace `MONTH` with `EXTRACT('month' FROM ...)` or other depending on the type of your DB backend..

Comment: I already did it, but I got another question... see it please [My question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827380/sorting-by-year-month-django-filter) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827380/sorting-by-year-month-django-filter is so interesting for me working with filters I'm learning a lot tonight