# Sorting by Year_Month Django filter

Tags: python, django, django-models

I try to show information order by year, month in a view, How can I improve my code for getting it?

Hint: I'm working in a report which shows sales ordering by year and month, Help me

Thanks.

views.py

```
 def ventas_mes_anio(request):
     ventas = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__range=["2011-01-01", "2013-12-31"])
     if ventas.is_valid():
         enero = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=1)
         febrero = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=2)
         marzo = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=3)
         abril = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=4)
         mayo = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=5)
         junio = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=6)
         julio = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=7)
         agosto = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=8)
         septiembre = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=9)
         octubre = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=10)
         noviembre = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=11)
         diciembre = Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=12)

    return render_to_response('ventasxproductosxmes.html',{'datos':ventas,'enero':enero,'febrero':febrero,'marzo':marzo,'abril':abril,'mayo':mayo,'junio':junio,'julio':julio,'agosto':agosto,'septiembre':septiembre,'octubre':octubre,'noviembre':noviembre,'diciembre':diciembre,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: you can create use queryset annotations to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: `ventas` is a `QuerySet` which does not have `is_valid`, perhaps you mean `if ventas.exists()` or directly evaluation `if ventas:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` of month names instead of individual month name variables. (Your locale must be set correctly for month_name to be in your language)

```
    import calendar
    months = dict(zip(calendar.month_name[1:], [Ventas.objects.filter(Fecha_registro__month=x) for x in xrange(1,13)]))
```

You can then simply return the `dict` as context. Or, if you don't wish to change anything in the template side.

```
ret = {'datos':ventas}
ret.update(months)
return render_to_response('ventasxproductosxmes.html',ret,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```