# Django Datetime Field Query - Order by Time/Hour

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am performing a query to return all `WorkOrder`s that have an appointment scheduled for today using the foreign key `Appointment`'s datetime field `start`. This is the query I am using and it is working exactly as expected.

```
WorkOrder.objects.filter(appointment__start__year=date.today().year, appointment__start__month=date.today().month, appointment__start__day=date.today().day)
```

I would like to sort them by date descending and hour ascending. 
The order I want would look something like this:

```
11-May-2014 08:00
11-May-2014 10:00
11-May-2014 12:00
10-May-2014 10:00
10-May-2014 13:00
09-May-2014 15:00
...
```

I have tried ordering it with commands such as:

```
.order_by("-appointment__start", "appointment__start__hour")
```

but that results in the following error:

```
FieldError: Join on field 'start' not permitted. Did you misspell 'hour' for the lookup type?
```

It seems I can only do

```
.order_by("-appointment__start")
```

Is there another way I should be doing this or is this just something I will have to live with?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Django version < 1.6? Because `datetime` field lookups by `hour` [were added in 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#hour). If so, then unfortunately you won't be able to access the `hour` in that way. However, you can use that method to access the `day`.

Thus, you can **change your `order_by` to**:

```
.order_by("appointment__start", "-appointment__start__day")
```

This will first order by datetime ascending (which will take care of hours) and then day descending.

**OR**, you can use the [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) modifier to select the hour from the datetime and order by it. [Here's an example selecting month from a datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236283/3096768). However, it will be a bit more complicated due to the `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I am using Django 1.6. Unfortunately I can't access __day, __hour, __month, __year, etc. from inside an order_by without it resulting in an error like so: "FieldError: Join on field 'start' not permitted. Did you misspell 'day' for the lookup type?" I will check out the extra field and worse case I might see about annotating a separate time field to sort by. Thank you for the help pcoronel.